# ReactJs -> Auto Complete Textbox using .net framework

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, reactjs.net

How to create auto complete textbox using reactJs in .net framework. [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var InputAutoComplete=React.createClass({
getInitialState: function () {
     return {
         input: '',
         selected: false
     }
 },
handleChange : function(event) {
this.setState({
  input: event.target.value,
  selected: true
});
},

liHandleClick: function(event) {
this.setState({
  input: event.target.innerText,
  selected: false
});
},
keyPressHandler : function(event){
if (this.state.selected) {
    var ul=$(this.refs.autoCompleteList.getDOMNode());
    var liSelected = ul.find('li.active');
    if(event.keyCode === 40) { //Down Arrow key press
        if(liSelected.length>0){
            liSelected.removeClass('active');
            next = liSelected.next();
            if(next.length > 0){
                liSelected= next.addClass('active');
            }else{
                liSelected=ul.find('li').eq(0).addClass('active');
            }
        }else{
            liSelected= ul.find('li').eq(0).addClass('active');
        }
    }else 
    if(event.keyCode === 38){//Up Arrow key press
        if(liSelected.length>0){
            liSelected.removeClass('active');
            next = liSelected.prev();
            if(next.length > 0){
                liSelected=next.addClass('active');
            }else{
                liSelected=ul.find('li').last().addClass('active');
            }
        }else{
            liSelected=ul.find('li').last().addClass('active');
        }
    }else 
    if(event.keyCode === 13){//Enter key press
        var selectedValue=liSelected.text();
        this.setState({
             input: selectedValue,
             selected: false
         });
    }
}
},
matches:function(input) {
const regex = new RegExp(input, 'i');
return this.props.options.filter(function(option) {
  return option.match(regex) && option !== input;
});
},
handleFocusChange:function(){//Binding keydown event onFocus textbox
document.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyPressHandler, false);
},
handleFocusOutChange:function(){//Unbinding keydown event onFocusOut textbox
document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.keyPressHandler, false);
},
render : function() {
    let autoComplete = null;
    var li = [];
    var selectedListData=this.matches(this.state.input).map( option => {return option;});
    if(selectedListData.length > 0)
    {
        for(var i=0;i<selectedListData.length;i++) {
            li.push(<li className="list-group-item" value={selectedListData[i]} onClick={this.liHandleClick} >{selectedListData[i]}</li> );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        li.push(<li className="list-group-item">{'No record found'}</li> );
    }
    if (this.state.selected) {
        autoComplete = (<ul ref="autoCompleteList" style={{position:'absolute',width:300+'px'}} className="list-group">{li}</ul>);
    }
return (
    <div>
      <input style={{width:300+'px'}} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} placeholder="Select..."
       onFocus={this.handleFocusChange}
       onBlur={this.handleFocusOutChange}
        value={this.state.input}/>
        <div className={'fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'} ></div>
      <br />
        {autoComplete}
    </div>
);
}
});
var  optionsData = ['britain', 'ireland', 'norway', 'sweden', 'denmark', 'germany', 'holland', 'belgium', 'france', 'spain', 'portugal', 'italy', 'switzerland'];

React.render(<InputAutoComplete options={optionsData}/>, document.getElementById('autocompleteTest'));
```